# How can i make infite loop to ask user if he wants to input another number?

Tags: python

how can i make my code to ask user if wants to input another number? I could barely make my code run without errors, i am a toddler at python. I struggled a lot to write the code below. I know that stackoverflow is not a code writing service. But my little brain hurts now and i can't continue without help. I want to say simply "Do you want to convert another number?"

```
import math
# Global definition 
#Base = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F] 

Base = [str (x) for x in range (10)] + [chr (x) for x in range (ord ('A'), ord ('A') +6)] 
h=[str(i) for i in range(10)]+["A","B","C","D","E","F"]


def BIN2DEC (string_num):
    num = string_num
    if num == 0:
        return '0'
    bin_str = ''
    while num > 0:
        bin_str = str(num % 2) + bin_str
        num = num / 2
    return bin_str



def HEX2DEC (string_num): 
    return str (int (string_num.upper (), 16)) 

# Dec2bin 
# Decimal to binary 

def dec2bin (string_num): 

    num = int (string_num) 
    mid = [] 
    while True: 
            if num == 0: break 
            num, rem = divmod (num, 2) 
            mid.append (Base [rem]) 

    return''. join ([str (x) for x in mid [:: -1]]) 

# Dec2hex 
# Decimal to hexadecimal 

def DEC2HEX (number):
    n = long(number ,16)
    if (n < 0):
        print(0)
    elif (n<=1):
        print n,
    else:
        DEC2HEX( n / 16 )
        x =(n%16)
        if (x < 10):
            print(x), 
        if (x == 10):
            print("A"),
        if (x == 11):
            print("B"),
        if (x == 12):
            print("C"),
        if (x == 13):
            print("D"),
        if (x == 14):
            print("E"),
        if (x == 15):
            print ("F"),

# Hex2tobin 
#The  hexadecimal to bry 
def HEX2BIN (hex_string):
    s = int(hex_string, 16) 
    num_digits = int(math.ceil(math.log(s) / math.log(2)))
    digit_lst = ['0'] * num_digits
    idx = num_digits
    while s > 0:
        idx -= 1
        if s % 2 == 1: digit_lst[idx] = '1'
        s = s / 2
    return ''.join(digit_lst)

# Bin2hex 
# Binary to hexadecimal 

def BIN2HEX (string_num): 
    return DEC2HEX (BIN2DEC (string_num))

my_num = 0
my_num = raw_input("Insert binary,decimal or hexadecimal:")

while(my_num != 0):

    if my_num[0:2] == "0x" or my_num[0] == "x":
        print HEX2BIN(my_num)
        print HEX2DEC(my_num)
        break
    elif my_num[0:2] == "0b" or my_num[0] == "b" and all(x in "01" for x in my_num):
        print""
        print BIN2HEX(my_num)
        print BIN2DEC(my_num)
        break
    else:
        print dec2bin(my_num)
        print HEX2BIN(my_num)
        print long(my_num)
        break
my_num = 0
my_num = raw_input(":")
```

Comment: Try indenting the last two lines of your script so they're inside the `while` loop. It won't specifically say "Do you want to continue", but the user will be able to indefinitely enter more numbers.

Comment: Incidentally, `my_num[0:2] == "0b" or my_num[0] == "b" and all(x in "01" for x in my_num)` will never evaluate to True because "string starts with 'b'" and "string contains only 0 or 1" are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

```
print list(iter(lambda:raw_input("Enter Value, or 'q' to quit:"),"q"))
```

is my personal favorite way

`iter` makes an iterator (you need to look it up)

it takes an optional no-argument function that it will continually call until it receives the second argument

Comment: If he's a new user, maybe explain your answer a bit? I doubt a new user would immediately get iterators and lambdas. It's a beautiful solution, but he'll never know what it's doing just by looking at it

Comment: lol im not in a very explainy mood :P but i added a little tiny bit :P